# Graduated Site Privileges (aka Where's my options gone?!?)

Tags: discussion

With the launch of the new site design we are now fully graduated, thanks to everyone here contributing questions and answers and building a community to get us to this point.

As a fully graduated site this means we now have the final [privilege reputation levels](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) in place.

This does mean that a lot of people will find their access to the site has dropped, however don't worry. Keep writing those excellent questions and answers and you'll get back to it in no time :)

Comment: True. :( I miss those reviews already... But one day... :)

Comment: @T3H40 You should have access to some of the queues still. But your access will only grow from here on out :)

Comment: I know :) I always knew this day would come - still sad though... But hey! We have an amazing new design! :)

Comment: More importantly, *let's keep voting up good content*.

Answer (score 7):

You do know that only 10 people have 20K points here?

Graduating doesn't mean you suddenly get higher traffic.  It would make more sense to ramp up the marks or scale it with the actual amount of voting done in a month.

Comment: 20k is the top but it's actually not that important -- that brings answer deletion, which can also be done through the review queues.  The really important privileges for site maintenance are reviews and close/reopen votes, which come at lower levels.  SE does look at how many users have key privileges when deciding whether a site is ready for graduation.  (By the way, if I recall correctly Workplace had 7 20k users at graduation, and that wasn't a problem for us.)

Comment: Some sites have struggled after graduation as they had a massive reduction in the number of people with access to the queues etc. That won't be a problem for us...